# Factorizacion LU usando eliminacion gaussiana en C++

Tags: c++

Muy buen día!
Estoy tratando de implementar la factorización LU usando eliminación gaussiana (mi post anterior fue utilizando el método Doolitle) pero no sé qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal. En papel, todo funciona pero el código no me está funcionando, me arroja valores incorrectos en la matriz L y U.

Muestro el código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
int i=0,j=0,k=0,n=0;

std::cout << "\t\tDESCOMPOSICION LU";
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "NOTA: El orden de la matriz debe ser mayor o igual que 2 y entero." << std::endl;
std::cout << "Ingresa el orden de la matriz: ";
std::cin >> n;

//Comprobacion de ingreso de un valor correcto para el orden de la matriz
if(n<=1){
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "No ha ingresado un valor correcto. Cerrando el programa...";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
} else {
    float A[n][n]={0}, L[n][n]={0}, U[n][n]={0};
    std::cout << "La matriz es de " << n << "x" << n <<".";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    //Obtencion de los elementos de la matriz A de coeficientes
    std::cout <<"Ingrese los coeficientes de la matriz A: ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            std::cout << "Ingrese el elemento A["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"]: ";
            std::cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    //Descomposicion LU

    //Copiar la matriz A en la matriz U para su triangulacion sin afectar la matriz original
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            U[i][j]=A[i][j];
           }
    }

    //Comprobacion de que la copia fue correcta
    /*for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            std::cout << U[i][j] << "    ";
           }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }*/

    //Llenado de ceros y unos en posiciones conocidas de la matriz L
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(i==j){
                L[i][j]=1;    //Unos en la diagonal de L
            } else if(i>j){
                L[i][j]=0;     //Ceros encima de la diagonal para la matriz L
            }
        }
    }
    //Llenado del resto de L y eliminacion Gaussiana en la matriz U
    double a;       //Sirve para llenar la matriz L y para la triangulacion de U
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        for(i=1;i-1<n;i++){
            a=-(U[i][j])/(U[j][j]);
            std::cout << "a [" << i << "]= " << a;
            for(int k=j; k<n; k++){   //Sirve para que la transformacion elemental afecte a toda la fila actual
                U[i][k]+=a;
            }
            if(i>j){
                L[i][j]=a;
            }
            a=0;
        }
    }


    //Mostrar en pantalla la matriz L
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Matriz L:";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            std::cout << L[i][j] <<"   ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n    ";
    }

    //Mostrar en pantalla la matriz U
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Matriz U:";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    ";

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            std::cout << U[i][j] <<"   ";;
        }
        std::cout << "\n    ";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Explico lo que trato de hacer:

Copio la matriz A (dada por el usuario) en la matriz U y luego escalono esta última obteniendo en cada iteración los valores que uso para dicha eliminación y relleno la matriz L (método clásico de descomposición o factorización LU).

Les agradecería mucho cualquier recomendación.

Tengan una excelente semana!

Comment: No directamente relacionado con tu pregunta, pero creo que es mejor que hagas un bucle `do-while` (o `while`) en caso de que el valor de `n` sea menor que 2, ya que se ve medio feo que el programa se cierre ahí mismo sin posibilidad de reingresar otro valor para `n`.

Comment: Tendré eso en cuenta, gracias!